# invalid constant value in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

How to fix this Constant value error

```
                  actions: [
                IconButton(
                   
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.cancel,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ), onPressed: () { 
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                       },
                    )

              ]
```

[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byjnk.png)

I have provided a code snippet for a Flutter application that includes an IconButton widget with an icon for the cancel button. When the button is pressed, the current screen is displayed using `Navigator.pop(context)` How to implement pop from navigation layer ?

Comment: Remove const keyword from AlertDialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on your `AlertDialog`.

You just need to remove `const` before `AlertDialog`.

Comment: this problem has clear . thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

There will be a const before the dialog box code. Please remove it.